# Combinatorics: Using binomial coefficients to figure out playing card combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this sample problem from my notes about how to find different 5-card poker hands from a standard 52-card deck. Can someone explain to me what's going on? I don't get why the `50` turned into a `5` and the `48` turned into a `4` (In my notes the 50 and 48 are crossed out and have a 5 and 4 written by them but I couldn't figure out how to do that in LaTeX).

$\binom{52}{5} = \frac{52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48}{5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1} = 52 * 51 * 5 * 49 * 4 = 2,598,960$

What would happen if I wanted to do a 6-card hand? Would the process be the same, making it

$\binom{52}{6} = \frac{52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48 * 47}{6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1} = ??? = ???$

Comment: Looks like they simplified the fraction:  $\frac {50}{5*2}=5$ and $\frac {48}{4*3}=4$.

Comment: So they basically just checked if each number had a simplification? How did they decide that?

Comment: The number of ways to choose $5$ out of $52$ different cards is $\binom{52}{5}=\frac{52!}{5!\cdot(52-5)!}$ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think there's a "decision", so to speak...were I doing it, I'd go term by term (in the denominator).  Need to cancel the $5$?  Well, it divides $50$ evenly so do that.  Now need to cancel the $4$? Here, I'd have used $\frac {52}{4}=13$ personally.  Always kill off the largest factors if you can.  Next the $3$?  Again, I'd have used $\frac {51}{3}=17$.  Finally, I'd have used $\frac {48}{2}=24$. Thus, I'd have wound up with $13*17*10*49*24$. There's no unique way to proceed, in other words.  But the idea is solid:  simplify the fraction before you start multiplying.